# Outputting HTML in PHP, is there any upside to using ob_start or simply echo $html?

Tags: php, html, ob-start

Obviously there are usability and readability differences, but are there any advantages or disadvantages to the methods below – especially performance-wise?

```
function method1() {
  ob_start();
  ?><div>some html</div><?php
  echo ob_get_clean();
}

function method2() {
  ?><div>some html</div><?php
}

function method3() {
  echo '<div>some html</div>';
}
```

In particular between `method1` and `method2`, does the added `ob_start()` cause a performance hit? Do I even need to use it when outputting HTML?

Answer (score 1):

The "typical" use for `ob_start()` is to buffer the output so that you can still use functions like `setcookie`, `header` and others without having to worry about "did I output something already?", it'll work. Honestly I think that should be default behaviour but that's just me.

`ob_start()` gains real power when you give it a callback, however. I personally have this:

```
ob_start(function($html) {
    return preg_replace('/\r?\n\t*/','',$html);
});
```

This strips out newlines (and subsequent tabs) from the HTML source before sending it to the browser, thus minifying it.

Comment: Cool, I have been experimenting with ob_start and the fact that it maintains the line breaks tabs and everything else sometimes comes handy and sometimes cause ugly code, I was looking for ways to deal with it, thanks for the example. I still wonder about the performance implications of it tho